# How to pass function from parent to a child in react?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a Dropdown component which uses onClick={this.openDrop} on a button located inside the component. The component is as following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Dropdown extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()

    this.state ={
      subMenu: ''
    }

    this.openDrop = this.openDrop.bind(this)
    this.closeDrop = this.closeDrop.bind(this)
  }

  closeDrop(){
    this.setState({subMenu: ''}, ()=>{
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeDrop)
    })
  }

  openDrop(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({subMenu: 'open'}, ()=>{
      document.addEventListener('click', this.closeDrop)
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className={`btn-group ${this.state.subMenu}`}>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-default dropdown-openDrop" onClick={this.openDrop}>
          Action <span className="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" className="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to get the inner content as a props.children as following:

```
  render(){
    return (<div className={`btn-group ${this.state.subMenu}`}>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
```

And use it as following

```
<Dropdown>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default dropdown-openDrop">
          Action <span className="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" className="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
</Dropdown>
```

But the problem is that I cannot pass the onClick={this.openDrop} into the button.

How can I pass the onClick={this.openDrop}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all the children of a component using `React.Children`. And we can clone every child with addition props with `React.clone(element,{ additionalProps })`. Here we check if the child is a button and add onClick props to it.

```
render() {
    const {children} = this.props;

    var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child => {
      if (child.type == "button") {
        return React.cloneElement(child, { onClick: this.openDrop })
      } else {
        return React.cloneElement(child)
      }
    });

    return (
      <div className={`btn-group ${this.state.subMenu}`}>{childrenWithProps}</div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the a props to your inner component so that when that props will received using `componentWillReceiveProps` then you can set your state, just an eg.

```
constructor() {
    this.state={
        toggle: false
   }  
}
toggleDropdown(){
    this.setState({toggle: true})
}
<Dropdown toggle={this.state.toggle}>
    <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleDropdown()} className="btn btn-default dropdown-openDrop">
      Action <span className="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul className="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" className="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</Dropdown>
```

You've to pass toggle prop to your dropdown component, Now within your Dropdown component you will receive that props and when it'll true you can `setState` of your submenu, just an idea, there are other many ways to do it.